# How to sync data between NoSQL and SQL Database?

Tags: python, linux, mongodb, postgresql

I'm currently working on NoSQL(MongoDB) For My Project but later i have to sync database between two different different db's

1. MongoDB
2. Postgrwsql

I am having experience on both but i would like to create bridge that can sync data bidirectional between two applications (one is based on mongodb and another is based on Postgresql ) and i am using python language for both application.

If somebody did something like this before or knows some kind of "best practices" and also if there reference available,  Please let me know.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i need help and reference if somebody have did like this and also if there is few reference who can share like how to do kind of thing

Comment: Are you facing a specific problem? You can use google to search for best practices.

Comment: i am not facing issue even i just want to know how can i start this kind of work , i just want sample work so that i can implement that for my product

Comment: F.ex. you can access MongoDB from within PostgreSQL with its foreign data wrapper http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createforeigndatawrapper.html  https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers#mongo_fdw -- and then, you can write changes with triggers. But there are no triggers in MongoDB, so I don't think this is possible in the other way.

Comment: pozs, Need your idea behind using xml-rpc or json-rpc for data sharing. i am new in mongodb

Comment: @Atul Jain, How did you solve this problem?